# How to make vertical text slider like this

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I'd like to ask you if you could help me creating a similar text slider like that from http://demo.codepark.co/floyd/

I want to create similar slides like these "WE ARE FLOYD" text which change vertically.

I created something like that [dead link removed] but I don't have any idea what slider scripts use and even how to make it works.

Answer (score 4):

http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/

Here is an example that does exactly what you want to do.

I would dissect this code to see what it does so you understand the principles of it (dont just blindly use plugins / scripts as learning how they work - even at a fundamental level will help you later.)

Answer (score 1):

I bought this theme, and I can tell you, that jquery - flexslider is used.

here a link to jquery flexslider with documentation

http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/flexslider#field_methods

use this parameters, and instead of img use eg p od h1 tag.

animation: "slide",
directionNav: false,
controlNav: false,
direction: "vertical",
slideshowSpeed: 5000,
animationSpeed: 1000,
smoothHeight: true